# Make a single page a wiki-style editable using PHP

Tags: software-rec, php, wiki

Are there any lightweight PHP solutions out there for making a single page editable by anyone who views it?

**Update:** and I don't mean like [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any 'single page' wikis, but check [Lionwiki](http://lionwiki.0o.cz/):

```
LionWiki is a minimalist Wiki engine programmed in PHP. It is extensible, templatable, file based (it doesn't need database like MySQL) and requires just one file to function.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can interest You: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TigerWiki, but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Lionwiki is a straight successor to it.